# understanding a quotient group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$
. Let $K$ be the subgroup of $G$ generated by $(3,6)$ and $(3,1)$. Describe the rank and invariant factors of the abelian groups $K$ and $G/K$.

My Try: Since $\phi : K \to G$ defined by $\phi(m(3,1)+n(3,6))=(m,n)$ is an isomorphism, then $K \cong \mathbb{Z}^2$ and hence rank of $K$ is $2$.

But I have problems in understanding the quotient group $G/K$. I already appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example is not too hard because $(0,5) \in K$, and it is not hard to see that $\{(i,j) : 0 \le i \le 2, 0 \le j \le 4\}$ is a transversal for $K$ in $G$, so $|G/K|=15$. The quotient group is cyclic with generator $(1,0)+K$.

The general method for solving this type of problem involves computing the Smith Normal Form of the matrix formed by the generators of $K$.